# Почему не видит значение?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
$token = $_GET["token"];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT token FROM Tokens WHERE token =? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($token));
echo $stmt->fetchColumn(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Ответ от сервера пустой.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: @Doofy ошибки нет, в том то и дело) Как исправить мою ошибку?

Comment: в токен например вот что : "asdadasdadas"

Comment: @Doofy если попадает в токене то, значение которе есть в бд , то он его и выдает, если нет такого значения в бд , то ответ пустой)
А у меня всегда пустой почему-то)

Comment: @Doofy поменял на то, как вы сказали, аналогично, ответ пустой)

Comment: @Doofy не вводите человека в заблуждение, в `execute` передаётся именно массив параметров. http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @Blacknife может вы подскажете?

Comment: @Blacknife прелесть в том, что запрос построен правильно(в админке проверял)

Comment: к сожалению я с PDO мало работал, но насколько помню `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` должен возвращать ассоциативный массив вида `array('token' => 'данные ячейки')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$token = $_GET["token"];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT token FROM Tokens WHERE token =? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($token));

if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    echo $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
}
```